# Apache2 does not restart after upgrade Debian wheezy and php 5.5

Tags: php, apache2

Just upgraded to Debian Wheezy from 6 and decided to upgrade to PHP 5.5 at the same time, only it was impossible to restart Apache which was running, but has since stopped.

```
service apache2 restart
apache2: Syntax error on line 236 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5_cgi.load: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
```

The lines mentioned above in the conf file are:

`# Include module configuration:`
`Include mods-enabled/*.load`
`Include mods-enabled/*.conf`

I tried to go back to PHP 5.4, but each time I reinstall only 5.5 comes back.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I don't know the exact cause, but I suspect that the configuration file is not compatible across versions.

For me, what worked was

```
apt-get purge apache2
apt-get install apache2
```